# Why is my team wiping in the middle of the siege engine fight?

Tags: destiny

Last night, my group was running the Wrath of the Machine raid and had gotten to the Siege Engine fight. We lost a few times, but eventually got the point where we were consistently clearing the first half (break the siege engine's panel off and jump on) of the fight.

About that time, we started having an issue. Every time we'd finish off the siege engine and jump up on it, it would get to the point where it breaks through the wall. Then, the screen would start fading to red and the whole squad wiped out.

The first time, we figured it's because one of our players jumped off to revive the people who had been dropped. The second time, we kept everyone on the engine, but still wiped. At that point, we jumped back to space to try to get the issue to reset itself. Over 3-4 more runs, we attempted variations of everyone of the very back of the engine, no one on the back, and everyone on the stairs in the middle of the engine. Each time, the game wiped us out with no apparent explanation.

Were we doing something wrong? Is this a problem that has been encountered/solved already?

Answer (score 2):

There are only 3 wipe mechanics in the Siege Engine encounter:

1. Everyone dies
2. A part is dropped into one of the holes in the map
3. The parts are not placed within the time limit

Since none of those actually happened, the only reasonable explanation I can come up with is that one or more of your fireteam members had poor connections, causing lag-related glitches.